# Clear dictionary every time web page refresh

Tags: python

This code returns a JSON datas in my localhost from pokeAPI (https://pokeapi.co/) already filtered. But everytime I reload the page my dictionary gets duplicated and I just want the original always. PS: the red mark on the picture shows the original dictionary and the rest of it is wrong.

```
#listas auxiliares
tipo = [] #aux tipo
habil = [] #aux habilidade
lista_hab = [] 
lista_tipo = []
lista_todos = []
lista_aux = []

#dicionários 
dicio_stat = {}
dicio_todos = {}
dicio_aux = {}

def pokemons(request):
    for i in range(1, 10):
        url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{i}"
        requisicao = requests.get(url)

        try:
            lista = requisicao.json()
        except ValueError:
            print("ERRO TIPO")


        dicio = {
            'ID': lista['id'],
            'Nome': lista['name'],
            'Tipo': lista_tipo,
            'Peso': lista['weight'],
            'Altura': lista['height'],
            'Habilidades': lista_hab,
            'Estatisticas': dicio_stat,
            'Link_img': lista['sprites']['other']['official-artwork']['front_default']
        }

        for a in lista['abilities']:
            #dic_abi[i['ability']['name']] = i['ability']['url']
            habil.append(a['ability']['name'])
        dicio['Habilidades'] = habil[:]
        lista_hab.append(dicio.copy())


        for s in lista['stats']:
            dicio_stat[s['stat']['name']] = s['base_stat']
        

        for t in lista['types']:
            #dic_type[i['type']['name']] = i['type']['url']
            tipo.append(t['type']['name'])
        dicio['Tipo'] = tipo[:]
        lista_tipo.append(dicio.copy())

        dicio_aux = dicio.copy()
        lista_aux.append(dicio_aux)

        dicio_todos['pokemons'] = lista_aux

        habil.clear()
        tipo.clear()
        dicio.clear()

    return JsonResponse(dicio_todos)
```

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm3Mv.png)

Comment: Put the list declarations also in the `pokemons` function.

Comment: thank you very much, that helped a lot